# How to open the PDF generated in new tab

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a Leave application project that generates a PDF file.
this is the code that generates the pdf after I click submit.

```
 $id = DB::table('leave')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->max('id');
    $data = leave::where('id', $id)->select('*')->get();
    $filename = auth()->user()->name." - S - ". "LEAVE - ".$randomString->randomString(8)."-".$request->filing_date.".pdf";
        $path = storage_path('app/leave_file/'.$filename);
        PDF::loadView('pdf_views.leave_pdf', $data[0])->setPaper('legal')->save($path);
        if(file_exists($path)){
            DB::table('leave_files')->insert([
                'filename' => $filename,
                'leave_id' => DB::table('leave')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->max('id'),
            ]);
        }
    
    return redirect()->route('leave')->with('success', "success");
```

I wonder if I can make the newly generated pdf open in the new tab after I click submit on my leave application. thank you to anyone who can help

Comment: Try PDF::loadView('pdf_views.leave_pdf', $data[0])->setPaper('legal')->save($path, 'I'); maybe works.

Comment: @EHFShahab i tried and it doesnt open the newly pdf file in the new tab

Comment: You can not open a new tab with an HTTP redirect. Opening the new tab needs to happen on the client side, the moment you _click_ to trigger this process.

Comment: Maybe have your view return a URL to the file instead of the file itself. Then you can have some JS to open that URL in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Laravel docs this is what you need: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#file-responses

> **File Responses**
>
> The file method may be used to display a file, such as an image or PDF, directly in the user's browser instead of initiating a download. This method accepts the path to the file as its first argument and an array of headers as its second argument:
>
> ```
> return response()->file($pathToFile);
>
> return response()->file($pathToFile, $headers);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Cache Facade, to store the generated pdf temporary.

```php
$uuid = Str::uuid();

return response()->stream(function () use ($uuid) {
    echo Cache::remember($uuid, 300, function() {
        return 'genertated pdf content'
    });
}, 200, [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition' => sprintf('attachment; filename=%s;', $uuid),
]);
```

Create a route to access to cached file. Name the route.
Now you can open it in a new tab from you frontend e.g. Generate the route with `route('routename', ['param' => 123])` and pass it to your FE with a REST endpoint for example.

```js
window.open(url,'_blank');
```